# How can I generate an error in magento to fail checkout?

Tags: magento, checkout, skinning

I'm a magento front-end developer and I need to style the failed checkout page, but I don't know how to get to it, anyone?

Comment: A screenshot would be very helpful which page do really mean.

Comment: That's the thing, I can't get a screenshot because I can't get to it. I need to make checkout fail somehow so I can see that page.

Answer (score 0):

After following the quick core code change shown [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/836/15128)

> Go to `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::successAction()`
>
> Comment the line `$session->clear();`. Now you can make one order and
>   refresh the page as often as you like.

for styling the success page, simply put through a test order and once you are on the success page just change the url from `/checkout/onepage/success/` to `/checkout/onepage/failure/`

**Don't forget to undo your modification to the core code to avoid the death penalty!**

Comment: You should post the code and comments from the link in your answer and use the link for reference only.

Comment: For others needing this, the file you need to TEMPORARILY edit is: /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php